# Internal forces in a pulley system standing still

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Assume that we have a pulley system such as the one illustrated here:

[image]

Now, let us assume that we stop the object with m2 from falling. Then the vertical forces W and T must be equal, but in opposite directions as there is no movement. However, would the force T acting on the object with m1 still be present as this is an internal force? If so, wouldn't the net forces in the horizontal direction be positive, and the system should still move?

If anyone can explain the forces acting on all parts of the system when we stop the object with m2 from falling, then I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Now, let us assume that we stop the object with m2 from falling. Then the vertical forces W and T must be equal, but in opposite directions as there is no movement.*

No so as you are missing the force stopping mass $m_2$ from falling.
If there is no friction that upward force on mass $m_2$ must be equal in magnitude to the weight of mass $m_2$ which in turn will mean that the tension in the string will be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, the object would fall if you stop and just release the object and If your hand is still there to stop then the equation for net force would be $T + N = W$ (if the string is tight and the horizontal surface has friction) and simply $N = W$ when the string is not tight and in this case it's not necessary to have surface friction less of with friction. And where $N$ is normal